# Nginx and CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, nginx, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, cors

I'm trying to set up cors on my nginx server.

I've put this to my virtual host settings to location section:

```
 if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://client.cors-api.appspot.com';
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    #
    # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    #
    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 204;
 }
 if ($request_method = 'POST') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://client.cors-api.appspot.com';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
 }
 if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://client.cors-api.appspot.com';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
 }
```

Seems, that everything is ok, but when I'm trying to launch cors tests I'm getting XMLHttpRequest error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxxxxx.xxx/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://client.cors-api.appspot.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Seems, that OPTIONS method passed ok, but GET ends with an error. What it could be?

nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Comment: does it work if you put `'*'` instead of `'http://....'` - I ask because other than the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` entry, that looks like a copy/paste of every `enable CORS with nginx` page I've seen :p

Comment: I assume you've restarted `nginx` after making the changes

Comment: Yeah, it's really copypaste. I've tried '*' with and without credentials, but result was the same.
Of course, I've restarted nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I make an assumption that you have other `add_header` directives in that `location`. If so, there might be an unexpected behavior.

Take a look at the example:

```
location /somelocation {
    add_header      "Header 1"      "Value 1";

    set $a 1;
    if ($a = 1) {
        add_header      "Header 2"      "Value 2";
    }

    set $b 2;
    if ($b = 2) {
        add_header      "Header 3"      "Value 3";
    }

    return    200    "Some response\n";
}
```

In this case only `Header 3` will be attached to the response. This is how standard `ngx_headers` module works.

You may consider recompiling Nginx with [`ngx_headers_more` module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) to get more freedom when working with headers, or setting CORS headers not with Nginx, but with programming language your backend is written in.

Answer (score 0):

God damned! I haven't noticed another location section with php-fpm settings, so it overrides my cors with an empty settings.

Everything is ok now, thanks for answers.
@Curious, you were also right about nginx compiling.